# I can't get rowid parent of a subgrid in jquery grid plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, struts2, grid

I work in a Struts 2 project with the Jquery Grid Plugin (3.3.3)

I'm using a grid (`<sjg:grid>`) and subgrid nested component . In the `editurl` action of my subgrid I've implemented `rowid` where it will be the row id of the parent.

```
private String rowid;

public void setRowid(String rowid) {
    this.rowid = rowid;
}

public String getRowid(){
    return rowid;
}
```

When I edit (or add) a record across the dialog panel `rowid` is set properly, but if I edit it inline (`editinline="true"`) the  `setRowid` method don't run.

¿What can i do to get the rowid parent "working inline"?

Thanks